# Cross Domain call through Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am using below script to send cross domain ajax call.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
var uniqcod=$(".abc").attr('id');   
$.ajax({
    url:'abc.com',
    data:{uniId:uniqcod},
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'callback',
    crossDomain: true,
    jsonpCallback:"jsonpCallback",
    success: function(result){},
    error: function() {console.log('Failed!');
    console.log(arguments); }
    });

function jsonpCallback(data){
    document.getElementById(uniqcod).innerHTML=data.content;
}

});
```

But the problem is this script is not going in jsoncallback function. Every time i call this function, it shows failed message in console.

Comment: change `"jsonpCallback"` to `jsonpCallback` methinks

Comment: does the URL you are hitting support JSONP?

Comment: Try to remove "jsonp: 'callback', crossDomain: true, jsonpCallback:"jsonpCallback"," I think you don't need them.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do a cross-domain request if the server you're requesting from sends back CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing) headers.

If it's a server you're in control of, then you just need to make that change.

If not, you'll need to proxy the data via a server you *do* control to add the appropriate headers.

Edit: Or if it's JSONP then you need to make sure that the server you're requesting from actually supports JSONP.

Comment: That's not the problem. Because (Cross-origin resource sharing) headers are also included on the server where i am sending request. problem is somewhere in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make cross domain calls using jQuery, unless you are authenticated. However, you can make use of YQL (Yahoo Query Language) and make some calls and get xml, json formatted data.

See the example below.

```
function requestCrossDomain( site, callback ) {  

    // If no url was passed, exit.  
    if ( !site ) {  
        alert('No site was passed.');  
        return false;  
    }  

    // Take the provided url, and add it to a YQL query. Make sure you encode it!  
    var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from html where url="' + site + '"') + '&format=xml&callback=cbFunc';  

    // Request that YSQL string, and run a callback function.  
    // Pass a defined function to prevent cache-busting.  
    $.getJSON( yql, cbFunc );  

    function cbFunc(data) {  
    // If we have something to work with...  
    if ( data.results[0] ) {  
        // Strip out all script tags, for security reasons.  
        // BE VERY CAREFUL. This helps, but we should do more.   
        data = data.results[0].replace(/<script[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/script>/gi, '');  

        // If the user passed a callback, and it  
        // is a function, call it, and send through the data var.  
        if ( typeof callback === 'function') {  
            callback(data);  
        }  
    }  
    // Else, Maybe we requested a site that doesn't exist, and nothing returned.  
    else throw new Error('Nothing returned from getJSON.');  
    }  
}
```

Comment: I am handling this problem from both ends. I have included header('content-type: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('content-type: Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET');
header('content-type: text/javascript'); on the server. But problem is still the same.

Comment: are you getting any error ? if so, could you share the error text and error status code ?